# Как сделать коло с помощю css html?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать коло с помощью css html?

Мне нужно именно кола рамки радиус, то есть вот так как на фото как сделать?  То есть сам процент заполнения эта белая штучка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Она еще и прозрачная в центре, или можно покрасить желтым?

Comment: центр прозрачний

Answer (score 5):

```js
// Радиус окружности
const radius = 37.5;

// Длина пути круга
const total_length = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

// Одна восьмая часть от всего пути
const one_eighth = total_length / 8;

// Половина пути
const half = total_length / 2;

// Три четвертых
const three_quarters = total_length * 0.75;

console.log('Полная длина пути:', total_length);
// Полная длина пути: 235.61944901923448

console.log('Одна восьмая:', total_length - one_eighth);
// Одна восьмая: 206.16701789183017

console.log('Половина:', half);
// Половина: 117.80972450961724

console.log('Три четвертых:', total_length - three_quarters);
// Три четвертых: 58.90486225480862
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

svg {
    background-color: #fdca06;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
}

svg text {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: middle;
}

svg circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 25;
    stroke: #252524;
}

svg circle:last-child {
    stroke: #fff;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    stroke-dasharray: 235.61944901923448;
}

.animate-circle {
    animation: animate-circle 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-circle {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 235.61944901923448;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        stroke-width: 25;
        stroke: #2ecc71;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-width: 5;
        stroke: #e74c3c;
    }
    to {
        stroke-width: 25;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        stroke: #2ecc71;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50" y="50">Анимация</text>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" class="animate-circle" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50" y="50">Одна восьмая</text>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" stroke-dashoffset="206.16701789183017" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50" y="50">Половина</text>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" stroke-dashoffset="117.80972450961724" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50" y="50">Три четвертых</text>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="37.5" stroke-dashoffset="58.90486225480862" />
</svg>
```

Comment: превосходно получилось!

Comment: если из целого отнять одну восьмую - одна восьмая никак не получится в результате

Comment: добавь описание что происходит в коде

Comment: @Grundy в коде происходит **magic**

Comment: @MoloF, очевидно в этом случае стоит удалить ответ. Раз ты не знаешь что происходит в коде, есть вероятность что его выполнение несет какие-либо деструктивные последствия

Comment: А учитывая ошибку непосредственно в ответе, то он еще и неверный.

Comment: @MoloF, не должен, но стоило бы это сделать, раз ты не знаешь, что происходит в коде, который ты выложил в ответ. Так как в ответе нет никаких пояснений, код может выполнять что угодно. В том числе и деструктивные действия. Об ошибке указано в комментарии выше.

Comment: теперь у тебя в два раз больше ошибок стало :) Под кодом имелся ввиду весь сниппет, включая html и css части, а не только js.

Comment: @Grundy если в коде ошибки, то как оно работает???? https://i.imgur.com/ySn1qjp.jpg

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111051/discussion-between-grundy-and-molof).

Comment: очень просто, не все ошибки приводят к полной неработоспособности системы
есть логические ошибки
есть математические и т.д.

Comment: Так как ты не можешь сделать описание решения, есть вероятность, что ты откуда-то взял предоставленный код, а не написал его сам, следовательно нужно добавить ссылку на источник.